# Packet Capture sees 1434 bytes instead of 1500 bytes

Tags: packet-capture, mtu

I am using sockets in python to send files, and I am doing a packet capture while sending these files. However, I find that each packet is 1434 bytes instead of the 1500 bytes (MTU is set at 1500 bytes on my system).

I have attached some screenshots of the packet capture. I need to send the packet at 1500 bytes rather than the 1434 bytes, can some one tell me what's going on?

[image: packet capture 1]
[image: packet capture 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP sends whatever-sized segments it wants to send over the wire; you can't control that from the socket layer.  Perhaps the remote machine is only offering a window big enough to send 1314 bytes of data (1314 + 14 bytes of Ethernet header + 20 bytes of IP header without options + 20 bytes of TCP header without options = 1368), or perhaps the [congestion window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congestion_window) isn't open wide enough to send more data.

Furthermore, you shouldn't *have* to control that.  TCP provides a sequenced byte stream; packet boundaries are *NOT* significant in TCP!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply, I had the same idea but the tool I am working on required a packet to be sent at 1500 bytes. I solved the problem by changing the requirements of that tool.

Comment: If the tool required individual TCP segments to be a certain size, the tool was broken, and fixing it by removing that requirement was the right idea.  (To read *N* bytes from a TCP connection, a single `read()` won't work - you may have to keep reading until you've gotten all *N* bytes.  Make sure you don't read *more* than *N* bytes unless you can process the remaining bytes later.)